# Migration from Spark 2.4.0 to Spark 3.1.1 caused SortMergeJoin to change to BroadcastHashJoin

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently working on a Spark migration project that aims to migrate all Spark SQL pipelines for Spark 3.x version and take advantage of all performance improvements on it. My company is using Spark 2.4.0 but we are targeting to use officially the 3.1.1 for all Spark SQL data pipelines **but without AQE enabled yet**. The primary goal is to keep everything the same but use the newest version. Later on, we can easily enable AQE for all data pipelines.

For a specific case, right after the spark version change, we faced the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs. You can increase the timeout for broadcasts via spark.sql.broadcastTimeout or disable broadcast join by setting spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1
```

We investigated this issue and looking at Spark UI logs, we noticed a change in the query plan as follows:

Spark 2.4.0:

[image]

Spark 2.4.0 is using the default `SortMergeJoin` to do the join operation between the `tbl_a` and `tbl_b`, but when we look at query plan from new Spark 3.1.1:

[image]

We can notice that instead of `SortMergeJoin` it is using the `BroadcastHashJoin` to do the join between `tbl_a` and `tbl_b`. Not only this, but if I'm not wrong, the `BroadcastExchange` operation is occurring on the big table side, which seems strange from my perspective.

As additional information, we have the following properties regarding the execution of both jobs:

- `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` = 10Mb
- `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled` = false # AQE is disabled
- `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` = 200
  and other non-relevant properties.

Do you guys have any clue on why this is happening? My questions are:

- Why Spark 3 has changed the join approach in this situation given that AQE is disabled and the `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` is much smaller than the data set size?
- Is this the expected behavior or could this represents a potential bug in Spark 3.x?

Please, let me know your thoughts. I appreciate all the help in advance.

**UPDATE - 2022-07-27**

After digging into Spark code for some days, and debugging it, I was able to understand what is happening. Basically, the retrieved statistics are the problem. Apparently, Spark 3 gets the statistics from a Hive table attribute called `rawDataSize`. If this isn't defined, than it looks  for `totalSize` table property, as we can see in the following source code:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/execution/PruneHiveTablePartitions.scala#L69

During my tests, this property presented a very small number (way lower than the autoBroadcastThreshold property) making Spark Optimizer think it was safe to broadcast the right relation, but when the actual broadcast operation happened, it showed a bigger size, approximately the same as in the picture for the right relation, causing the timeout error.

I fixed the issue for my test by running the following command on Hive for a specific partition set:

```
ANALYZE TABLE table_b PARTITION(ds='PARTITION_VALUE', hr='PARTITION_VALUE') COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

The `rawDataSize` now is zero and Spark 3 is using the `totalSize` (has a reasonable number) as the relation size and consequently, is not using BHJ for this situation.

Now the issue is figuring out why the `rawDataSize` is so small in the first place or even zero, given that the hive property `hive.stats.autogather` is `true` by default (auto calculates the statistics for every DML command) but it seems to be another problem.

Comment: Hi @Igor Uchôa did you find out how to solve this issue? as I have the same issue but in my case, the right statistics are in place but still get this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Spark has made many improvements around joins.

One of them is :

AQE converts sort-merge join to broadcast hash join when the runtime statistics of any join side is smaller than the broadcast hash join threshold. This is not as efficient as planning a broadcast hash join in the first place, but it’s better than keep doing the sort-merge join, as we can save the sorting of both the join sides, and read shuffle files locally to save network traffic(if spark.sql.adaptive.localShuffleReader.enabled is true)

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-performance-tuning.html#converting-sort-merge-join-to-broadcast-join

Comment: As I mentioned, we are using Spark 3.1.1 and AQE is disabled, so this optimization shouldn't be occurring. Also, the autoBroadcastJoinThreshold is set for 10Mb, so it is not expected to broadcast such a big dataset.

Comment: I just edited the question stating that we are not using Spark 3 AQE yet.

Comment: Yeah, after some days of digging into the Spark code, I was able to figure out what is happening. Not solved the problem, but it's more clear. Updating my question...

Comment: when i switched to 3.1.1 from 2.4.0, i got the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: UnspecifiedDistribution 
does not have default partitioning` error